# Squirrel mail broken

Tags: linux, centos, squirrelmail

I'm new to web admin and I had an issue with squirrel mail not being able to receive mail, i found somewhere that said reinstalling doevcot would fix this and so i did and now i can't even login to squirrel mail.

I'm running Centos 5.6 with Ispconfig 3.

Following is the error log:

```
Jun 7 19:30:02 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:30:02 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:30:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[21648]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 19:30:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[21648]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 19:30:03 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 21648 exit status 1
Jun 7 19:30:03 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 19:35:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:35:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:35:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[21859]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 19:35:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[21859]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 19:35:03 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 21859 exit status 1
Jun 7 19:35:03 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 19:40:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:40:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:40:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[22065]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 19:40:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[22065]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 19:40:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 22065 exit status 1
Jun 7 19:40:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 19:45:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:45:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:45:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[22264]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 19:45:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[22264]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 19:45:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 22264 exit status 1
Jun 7 19:45:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 19:50:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:50:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:50:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[22463]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 19:50:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[22463]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 19:50:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 22463 exit status 1
Jun 7 19:50:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 19:55:02 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:55:02 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 19:55:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[22674]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 19:55:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[22674]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 19:55:03 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 22674 exit status 1
Jun 7 19:55:03 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 20:00:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:00:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:00:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[22873]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 20:00:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[22873]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 20:00:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 22873 exit status 1
Jun 7 20:00:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 20:05:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:05:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:05:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[23085]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 20:05:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[23085]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 20:05:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 23085 exit status 1
Jun 7 20:05:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 20:10:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:10:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:10:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[23286]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 20:10:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[23286]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 20:10:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 23286 exit status 1
Jun 7 20:10:02 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 20:15:02 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:15:02 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:15:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[24383]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jun 7 20:15:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[24383]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jun 7 20:15:03 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 24383 exit status 1
Jun 7 20:15:03 localhost postfix/master[16032]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jun 7 20:15:14 localhost dovecot: dovecot: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=24407 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 7 20:18:00 localhost dovecot: Dovecot v1.2.17 starting up (core dumps disabled)
Jun 7 20:18:17 localhost postfix/postfix-script: stopping the Postfix mail system
Jun 7 20:18:17 localhost postfix/master[16032]: terminating on signal 15
Jun 7 20:18:52 localhost sendmail[25090]: alias database /etc/aliases rebuilt by root
Jun 7 20:18:52 localhost sendmail[25090]: /etc/aliases: 77 aliases, longest 10 bytes, 779 bytes total
Jun 7 20:18:52 localhost postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
Jun 7 20:18:52 localhost postfix/master[25136]: daemon started -- version 2.3.3, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 7 20:20:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:20:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:20:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[25249]: connect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:20:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[25249]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:20:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[25249]: disconnect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:25:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:25:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:25:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[25521]: connect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:25:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[25521]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:25:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[25521]: disconnect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:30:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:30:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:30:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[28635]: connect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:30:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[28635]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:30:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[28635]: disconnect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:35:02 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:35:02 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:35:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[28953]: connect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:35:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[28953]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:35:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[28953]: disconnect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:35:07 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:38:54 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:40:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:40:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:40:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[29212]: connect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:40:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[29212]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:40:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[29212]: disconnect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:45:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:45:01 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jun 7 20:45:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[29412]: connect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:45:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[29412]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
Jun 7 20:45:01 localhost postfix/smtpd[29412]: disconnect from localhost.brown[127.0.0.1]
```

I've tried installing another mail client "RoundCube", I've deleted and recreated the mail domain and mailboxes for it, but still nothing. It's as though the mail client(s) can't validate the users details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with SquirrelMail itself. SquirrelMail is just a web-frontend, all the "real" errors related to mail happen at IMAP/SMTP level. From the logs I would think your server does not have `saslauthd` running, or alternatively path to it has been misconfigured in Postfix/Dovecot settings.

Comment: Thanks... but i've broken it proper in the time prior to your answer, so am in the process of reinstalling the os...